# How to provide an option to choose number of records in a page - react table?

Tags: reactjs, react-table

Using react table for displaying data, How can i provide an option for the user to choose number of rows displayed ?
Something like :

[image: "Showing"]

Thanks in advance,

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/examples/pagination

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table),

You have to provide props to `<ReactTable />`

```
showPageSizeOptions= {true}
pageSizeOptions= {[5, 10, 20, 25, 50, 100]}
defaultPageSize= {2}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zh9fap)

Comment: thanks, but i have a customer pagination component, which looks somethiing like this:https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-custom-pagination-with-react#toc-the-pagination-component , i think that overrides the pagination option i give, any idea i can incorporate it in the custom component ?

Comment: Is there any specific reason for not using default pagination?

Comment: @ravibagul91 How to add "all" as an option in the list?

Answer (score 1):

You can control the number of rows to be displayed in react-table by using the prop `pageSizeOptions`.

It accepts the array of integers. eg:

```
pageSizeOptions: [5, 10, 20, 25, 50, 100]
```